# Emacs rmail and gmail (IMAP) and google contacts

Tags: emacs, gmail, imap

It's been a few years since somebody asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132

So, I'll ask it again.

Despite several google searches and having a look at the rmail website and the Emacs manual, I cannot find any tutorials for an rmail beginner.

Does anybody know of an rmail tutorial - or example .emacs - that will:

1. get me set up with IMAP (specifically gmail)
2. auto-complete recipients using my google address book

If so, I'd be really very pleased.

I'm **specifically** interested in `rmail`, not `gnus` or `wanderlust` or any of those other ones.

Comment: For the address book, see here: http://julien.danjou.info/blog/2011/google-contacts-for-emacs

Answer (score 0):

Movemail supports the imaps protocol (imap+ssl) but rmail doesn't recognize the prefix "imaps:" (same for pop and pops). I've requested for an enhancement, but meanwhile it shouldn't be that difficult to get it working yourself (see rmail.el). Otherwise, just use offlineimap, which is also great for many other reasons.

Comment: I ended up finding `notmuch` and using `offlineimap`. I really like notmuch but it would be an interesting curiosity to use `rmail`.